# How to use JMock to verify a certain time has elapsed between two method calls?

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I am using JMock and JUnit to test a program. I want to verify that a certain time elapses between two method calls, how would I be able to do this? I was trying to look through the javadocs for JMock and I haven't had any luck. Maybe there isn't a way?

Alternatively, if this can be done with JUnit that would work as well.

```
   context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        // Set up action that causes the change of state
        oneOf(lightTimerInterfaceMock).startTimer(5);
        oneOf(lightDeviceInterfaceMock).turnLightOnFullBrightness();'
        // I want to verify 5 seconds has elapsed here
        oneOf(lightDeviceInterfaceMock).turnLightOff();
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use System.nanoTime():

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    // Set up action that causes the change of state
    // oneOf(lightTimerInterfaceMock).startTimer(5);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    oneOf(lightDeviceInterfaceMock).turnLightOnFullBrightness();'
    // I want to verify 5 seconds has elapsed here
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    boolean fiveSecondsPassed = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000000 >= 5
    oneOf(lightDeviceInterfaceMock).turnLightOff();
}});
```

Comment: @user1166935 It might be better to write the `1000000000` as `1e9` so it's more readable and clear that it's converting nanoseconds to seconds -- as it is, it's just a mass of zeros. If you write it as `1e9` it's much clearer.

Comment: @MiguelJ. It will, with slight imprecision of time needed for both startTime and endTime assignments

Comment: When I do context.assertIsSatistfied(); then do assertEquals(fiveSecondsPassed, false); won't that variable be out of scope?

Comment: @MiguelJ. It will be out of scope since it is local variable. Make it global :)